Stacked column chart
I'm trying to create a stacked column chart.
The code that I have written shows the values in the columns in a reverse order as well as I am unable to change my own colours. When I specify my won HEX, I get grey columns.
Can you please have a look at it?
I am also attaching pictures with my data and how I would like the chart to look like in the excel, and my result in R.
Data and Desired Chart in Excel
Chart in R
Thank you, Erika
Here is the code that I've managed to write:
col_names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D","E", "F", "G","H")  # Adjust as per your data

colnames(data) <- col_names

data_long$A <- factor(data_long$A, levels = rev(levels(data_long$A)))

# Reshape the data into long format
data_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = c(B:H), names_to = "X", values_to = "Value")

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = X, y = Value, fill = A)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "X Axis", y = "Y Axis", fill = "Y Axis") +
  theme_minimal()


It would be easier to help you if you shared your data in a reproducible way, you can use dput(data) or the constructive package. More info in this useful post.

You can use scale_fill_manual() to define the colors you wish to use.  Try this
yr = c("<1","1-2","2-3","3-5","5-10","10-20",">20")

A = c(28, 30, 11, 6, 12, 11, 2)

B = 0.9*A
B[7] <- B[7] + 10

C = 0.85 * A
C[7] = C[7] + 15

D = 1.1*A
D[1] = D[1] - 10

E = 1.2*A
E[2] = E[2] - 20

data = data.frame(yr,A,B,C,D,E)

library(colorspace)

# Reshape the data into long format
data_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = c(A:E), names_to = "X", values_to = "Value")

data_long$yr <- factor(data_long$yr, levels = rev(yr))  ##  order in which you wish to stack

mycolors <-  diverging_hcl(7, "Berlin")

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = X, y = Value, fill = yr)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "", y = "%") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors, name= "", breaks = yr) +  ### choose your own color
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))


